# Laravel add Picture from URL as attachment

Tags: laravel

I am getting a picture from an Api request and thats why I want to attach this to a E-Mail. Is there an easy way to do it?
I tried:

```
$message->attach($path);
```

**Edit / Solution** if Anybody has same problem. Just add:

```
$message->attach($url,['as'=>"your.png",'mime' => "image/png"]);
```